# Convert a date (string) into datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date in string format 'April 29, 2021'

- Notice how the format seems to be a bit different from the usually 04/29/2021.

I have tried the following but is producing an error.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('April 29, 2021', '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Is there anyway I could convert this date into a date format through some data manipulation?

Comment: what about `pd.to_datetime('April 29, 2021')`?

Comment: ah that worked. I completely forgot about this function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The `datetime` documentation, tutorials, and examples show you how to convert from many formats, and how to configure your own.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Datetime documentation has a table of possible formats for strptime and strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), and `%m` is labeled as 'Month as a zero-padded decimal number' (i.e. 01,02,...), which is clearly not what you need.

What you do need it `%B` 'Month as locale’s full name' (i.e. January, February, …, December (en_US); Januar, Februar, …, Dezember (de_DE))

So, your format should be:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('April 29, 2021', '%B %d, %Y')
```